# Fiddler change .swf file in referer of POST request

Tags: flash, https, fiddler

Ok, so I have this POST request that I captured and in it there is a referer that has a swf file referenced in the request Headers.(This is for an online flash game)  I obtained the swf decompiled it changed what I wanted and recompiled it.  Now I am trying to use fiddler to respond with the modified swf.  Not exactly sure if this is even what I want though.  I don't really know when this swf is run, but inside the action script in it I found where the value I want to change is calculated and I changed it so it was set to a specific value.  Also the swf contained action script files for what looked like custom encrypting.

So I am thinking that the swf is run on the client side(my browser) and then this outputs the request data send to the server?  Not sure of this though, I have been googling for days now on this stuff and haven't really found anything specifically describing what I want to know.

So if I am correct here I am stuck on trying to get Fiddler to tell my client browser to use the new swf file to generate the POST request data to the server.

I have been googling how to set up onBeforeRequest cases in action script and this on I had actually do something... Though the response from the server was always some kind of error.

```
if (oSession.oRequest.headers.ExistsAndContains("Referer","https://*******.com/gamelivedc/game-v214.v50825.swf")) 
            {
            if (oSession.uriContains("https://*******.com/api/bm/base/updatesaved")) 
            {
                oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
                oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Content-Type", "relevant/mime-type");
                oSession.ResponseBody = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\******\\Documents\\******\\game-v214.v50825.swf");              
            }
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Also what exactly is the referer?

and correct me if I have my head up my butt on any of this, please!

I was going to post images of Fiddler capture, but I can't because I don't have 10 rep points or whatever... So i have the images, if anyone knows how i can post them.

Comment: Oh also if I download the current swf file from the request, save it locally and put the reference to it in that fiddlerscript I am getting the same server error as when I point to the swf I modified.  I don't know why using the exact same swf taken from the request, but saved locally, is causing server errors.  I can only imagine the error is not actually with the swf file, but with how I am referencing it or something.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I figured it all out I'm pretty sure.  For anyone who cares.  Once finding out what the referer actually was it all seems to make sense now.  The referer is just the last page that the browser was viewing.  So since the referer contained a uri to the .swf file it means that the POST command I was looking at was not where the .swf file is being executed.  It is being executed on the packet connection before that, which for my purposes stinks, because the previous connection was a secure tunnel to the game server.

Basically this means that the swf is located on the game server and my browser connects to the server and runs the swf on the server and never runs it locally.  Meaning that this game is more secure than I thought, but since I was able to get my hands on the swf file I can run it locally and figure out how to generate a new html request using the swf then I can then force a POST request to the server with the altered html string in hopes that it will change the value of the variable on the server side.

Time will tell soon enough if I am right here.